# Unwrap a RSA key with AES key WebCrypto

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api

I'm trying to unwrap a RSA-OAEP key I just wrapped with an AES-GCM key.
The wrapping step seems to work. But when I tried to unwrap the key this exception throws : `DOMException: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements` which is not helping... I  ran the code on Firefox (78.15.0esr)

```
var iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12)); //create an initialization vector
var AESkey= await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey( //create an AES key => the wrapping key 
      {
        name: "AES-GCM",
        length: 256
      },
      true,
      ["wrapKey","unwrapKey"]
    );
var keyPair= await window.crypto.subtle.generateKey(//create an RSA keypair 
  {
    name: "RSA-OAEP",
    modulusLength: 4096,
    publicExponent: new Uint8Array([1, 0, 1]),
    hash: "SHA-256"
  },
  true,
  ["encrypt", "decrypt"]
);

var privateRSAKey=keyPair.privateKey;//=> this key will be wrapped 

//the function below works
var wrappedRSAKey= await window.crypto.subtle.wrapKey(// we wrap the RSA key with the AES 
        "jwk",
        privateRSAKey,
        AESkey, 
        {name: "AES-GCM",iv: iv}
    );


// The function below doesn't work X(
//exeception DataError: Data provided to an operation does not meet requirements
var unwrapped = await window.crypto.subtle.unwrapKey(
    "jwk",                     // it's the right format
    wrappedRSAKey,             // wrappedRSAKey is a ArrayBuffer 
    AESkey,                    // the encryption key
    {name: "AES-GCM",iv: iv},  // algorithm params for key encryption key

    {                      // algorithm params for key to unwrap
      name: "RSA-OAEP",
      hash: "SHA-256"
    },
    true,                  // extractability of key to unwrap
    ["encrypt", "decrypt"] // key usages for key to unwrap
  );
```

Any help to tell me what's wrong in unwrapKey would be appreciate !

Comment: In the `unwrapKey` method only the key usage `"decrypt"` must be used (and not additionally `"encrypt"`), because with a private key only decryption can be done, but not encryption (for encryption the public key is applied). With this fix the code works.

Comment: Of course !  Thank you for your help :)